# Automapper map source property of type A to destination List<B>

Tags: c#, automapper

My problem is that I need to both **convert type A to type B (and all nested types!)** and also convert a **single** object ('A') to a **List** of objects ('B') at the same time.

```
public class SourcePoco
{
    public ComplexTypeA MyProblem { get; set; }
    // there be more properties...
}

public class ComplexTypeA
{
    // ...more nested complex types
}
```

My question now is how to I map `MyProblem` to the following destination type:

```
public class DestinationPoco
{
    public IEnumerable<ComplexTypeB> MyProblems { get; set; }
    // there be more properties...
}
```

I do have the following mappings:

```
CreateMap<SourcePoco, DestinationPoco>()
   .ForMember(...);

CreateMap<ComplexTypeA , ComplexTypeB>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());

CreateMap<ComplexTypeA, IEnumerable<ComplexTypeB>>()
    .ConvertUsing<MyProblemConverter>();
```

I tried adding something like that - but it never gets invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Remove that converter. And try

`CreateMap<SourcePoco, DestinationPoco>().ForMember(d=>MyProblems,o=>o.MapFrom(s=>new[]{s.MyProblem}));`